# Pass a specific file through the php parser

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Does anyone know if it is possible to tell Apache to pass a specific file through the php parser ?

I want to try playing with "executable images", as described [here (youtube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeVz36FN61w).

I know about

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .jpeg
```

Is it possible to do it only for a specific file, though ?

Comment: You can try putting this directive inside a specific directory directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this:

```
<Files exec.jpg>
    DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you did the detection via the php script?  Say salty.jpg is the only one you want to redirect, everything else just load the jpg.

Use the above then use a php variable to detect the script name

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "salty.jpg"){
  <php code you want to run>
} else {
  <php code to load and display a jpg>
}
```